# Webcam Not Detected on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Predator PHN16-71)

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, webcam

I'm encountering an issue where my built-in webcam is not recognized by Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on my Predator PHN16-71 laptop. Interestingly, the webcam functions correctly on Windows, suggesting a software or driver issue specific to Ubuntu.

**System Details:**

- Laptop Model: Predator PHN16-71
- Ubuntu Version: 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
- Kernel Version: 6.5.0-21-generic

**Issue Description:**

The webcam is not detected by the system; applications like `guvcview` report "no video device (/dev/video0) found," and there are no /dev/video devices listed when checking the directory.

**Troubleshooting Steps Attempted:**

- Ran `lsusb`, which shows the webcam as "Quanta Computer, Inc. ACER HD User Facing" indicating the system at least recognizes the webcam hardware at a USB level.
- Attempted to manually load the `uvcvideo` module with no success in resolving the issue.
- Checked `dmesg | grep uvcvideo` (in previous troubleshooting steps) which suggested a failure to initialize the device but I'm unsure how to proceed with this information.

Questions:

1. Are there known compatibility issues with this kernel version (6.5.0-21-generic) and webcams, or specifically the one in my Predator laptop?
2. What additional steps can I take to troubleshoot and resolve the webcam detection issue on Ubuntu?
3. Could this be related to a missing driver or firmware, and if so, how can I verify and potentially fix this?

Any guidance, suggestions, or insights would be greatly appreciated as I rely on my webcam for several daily tasks and would prefer not to switch back to Windows for this functionality.

Comment: Is the Windows system that _does_ recognize the webcam installed on the same hardware (i.e., as dual booting system)? In that case, we can rule out BIOS settings, which would otherwise be a possible culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the Bash script you will find at
https://github.com/Giuliano69/uvc_driver-for-Quanta-HD-User-Facing-0x0408-0x4035-

It was created for an Aspire Nitro5, but should be hw independent.
It will download and install the sys tools needed for compilation, and the patched file.

It is discussed on the forum at
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2000947

I'm positively using it with version
Linux Astra2A 6.5.0-18-generic #18~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Feb  7 11:40:03 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Please report any malfunction on launchpad, so that other users can help you, or you can share your solutions.

BR

Comment: Thank you for updating that patch to 6.5. Can you also please send it to the kernel mailing list so that this makes its way into the upstream and Ubuntu kernels?

Answer (score 0):

That "Quanta Computer, Inc. ACER HD User Facing" driver is not yet in the main kernel, but [it is available as a patch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2000947):

```bash
# You can't use HWE 6.5:
# https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2000947/comments/124
sudo apt install linux-generic build-essential
sudo apt purge linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04
sudo apt autopurge
reboot

# From https://gist.github.com/aRmanNM/722eed098a35fa70b22063518a48c46f
git clone --depth 1 --branch v5.15 https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
cd linux/drivers/media/usb/uvc
sed -i '/static const struct usb_device_id uvc_ids/a\
    /* Quanta ACER HD User Facing */\
    { .match_flags  = USB_DEVICE_ID_MATCH_DEVICE\
            | USB_DEVICE_ID_MATCH_INT_INFO,\
      .idVendor = 0x0408,\
      .idProduct = 0x4033,\
      .bInterfaceClass = USB_CLASS_VIDEO,\
      .bInterfaceSubClass = 1,\
      .bInterfaceProtocol = UVC_PC_PROTOCOL_15,\
      .driver_info = (kernel_ulong_t) &(const struct uvc_device_info ) { .uvc_version = 0x010a, } },' uvc_driver.c
make -j -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-97-generic/build M=$PWD modules

# rename uvcvideo.ko to uvcvideo.ko.xz if required
name=uvcvideo.ko
target=/lib/modules/5.15.0-97-generic/kernel/drivers/media/usb/uvc/"$name"
sudo dpkg-divert --divert "$x".bak "$x"
sudo cp "$name" "$target"
sudo update-initramfs -u

sudo rmmod uvcvideo
sudo modprobe uvcvideo
```

Depending on your device, you may need to change 4033 to 4035.

Comment: @user68186 6.2 could work. 6.5 doesn't even compile. If WiFi doesn't work on 6.2, then you'll have to choose between WiFi and webcam